# Error using Hilt instrumentation TestCase Installin for SingletonComponent

Tags: android-testing, dagger-hilt, android-instrumentation

I'm getting the following Hilt error when I try to use a TestCase module to provide mocks for my instrumentation testing.

Here is the error

```
[Hilt]
public final class TestModules {
             ^
  @TestInstallIn#replaces() can only contain @InstallIn modules, but found: [com.davidozersky.posterpal.repo.UserRepository]
```

Here is my AppModule (real objects in project sourcesets)

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideJobApi(): JobsRetroInterface {
        val interceptor: Interceptor = object : Interceptor {
            @Throws(IOException::class)
            override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
                var request: Request = chain.request()
                val builder: Request.Builder =
                    request.newBuilder().addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
                request = builder.build()
                return chain.proceed(request)
            }
        }
        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .cache(null)
            .build()
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build()
        return retrofit.create(JobsRetroInterface::class.java)
    }


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideJobDao(database : JobDatabase) : JobDao {
        return database.jobDao
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDatabase(@ApplicationContext application : Context) : JobDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(application,
                JobDatabase::class.java,
                JobDatabase.Companion.NAME).fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build()

    }

//    @Provides
//    @Singleton
//    fun provideJobUseCases(repository: JobsRepository): UseCases {
//        return UseCases(
//            getJobs = GetJobsFromDatabase(repository,)
//        )
//    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideFireBaseAuth(): FirebaseAuth {
        return FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideUserRepository() : UserRepository {
        return UserRepositoryImpl(FirebaseAuth.getInstance())
    }

}
```

Here is the TestCase module.  I am not doing anything fancy here, just want to replace a singletonComponent with a mock object

```
package com.davidozersky.posterpal

import android.app.Activity
import com.davidozersky.posterpal.api.JobsRetroInterface
import com.davidozersky.posterpal.database.JobDao
import com.davidozersky.posterpal.database.entities.*
import com.davidozersky.posterpal.database.relations.OwnerWithJobs
import com.davidozersky.posterpal.database.relations.jobworkerposter.JobPW
import com.davidozersky.posterpal.database.relations.posterworker.WorkerWithPosters
import com.davidozersky.posterpal.repo.JobsRepository
import com.davidozersky.posterpal.repo.UserRepository
import com.davidozersky.posterpal.repo.UserRepositoryImpl
import com.davidozersky.posterpal.ui.fragments.SignUpFragment
import dagger.Binds
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import dagger.hilt.android.components.FragmentComponent
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent
import dagger.hilt.testing.TestInstallIn
import io.mockk.mockk
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import retrofit2.Response
import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.inject.Singleton


@Module
@TestInstallIn(
    components = [SingletonComponent::class],
    replaces = [UserRepository::class]
)
object TestModules {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideUserService() : UserRepository {
        return FakeUserRepo()
    }

//    @Provides
//    @Singleton
//    fun provideJobRepo() : JobsRepository {
//        return FakeJobsRepo(mutableListOf())
//    }

//    @Binds
//    @Singleton
//    abstract fun bindUserRepository(
//        myUserRepository: FakeUserRepo
//    ) : UserRepository
//

    class FakeJobsRepo(override var appliedAndAcceptedJobs: List<JobPW>) : JobsRepository {
        override fun getDao(): JobDao {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override fun getApi(): JobsRetroInterface {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override suspend fun getAllJobs(): List<JobPW> {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override fun getAllJobsFlow(): Flow<List<JobPW>> {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override suspend fun getJobById(id: Int): JobPW? {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override suspend fun insertJob(job: Job) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override suspend fun getOwner(id: Int): OwnerWithJobs {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override suspend fun insertOwner(owner: Owner): Long {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override suspend fun getPoster(id: Int): Poster? {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override suspend fun insertPoster(poster: Poster) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override suspend fun getWorkerWithPoster(worker_id: Long): Flow<WorkerWithPosters> {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override suspend fun getJobsByAPI(): Response<List<JobPW>>? {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override suspend fun addWorkersToJob() {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override suspend fun addPostersToJob() {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override suspend fun saveJobToDatabase(job: JobPW): Long {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override suspend fun addWorkerToPoster(poster_id: Long, worker: Worker) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

    }

    class FakeUserRepo : UserRepository {

        suspend fun getUsers() = mockk<List<User>>()

        override fun checkForUser() {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override fun signUpWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: String?,
            password: String?,
            activity: Activity,
            signUpListener: SignUpFragment.SignUpListener
        ) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    }

}
```

[image: file structure]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry was a stupid mistake, needed to use replace with module name